# ListBox.SelectedItems is set when assigning ItemsSource in code-behind using async-await

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, listbox, itemssource

I have a ListBox and I assign its ItemsSource manually in the code behind. This works fine at first, but when I try to do it asynchronously it starts acting weird. Right after I assign the ItemsSource the SelectedItems is getting set to the first element in the list. I can clear the item selections but I really want to know what's causing this.

```
lbResults.ItemsSource = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return Context.ResultsList;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most probably caused by `ListBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. Change the setting to `false` and your issue will be resolved.

**XAML :**

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
```

**XAML.cs :**

```
lbResults.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = false;
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much. After doing some research on IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem, I found out that this is caused by ItemSource being sorted(which sets the CurrentItem) before I assign it to the ListBox.